# wget fetch image from different domain

Tags: download, wget

When downloading a page using `wget` with the `-p` option (page requisites), which downloads all the files that are necessary to properly display a given html page, including such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets. It seems like an image that belongs to a different domain (e.g. `www.google.com`) will not be downloaded. Is there a way to cause it to be downloaded as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-H` option (go to foreign hosts when recursive).